# Ovelay react native flatlist items

Tags: react-native, overlay, overlapping, flatlist

Guys why my flatlist items are not rendering over the succeeding text input. I can see my white background text input rendering over the flatlist items. I wan't to have the flatlist items over the text input.

```
const SearchScreen = () => {

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View>
               <TextInput
                   style={styles.textInput}
                   placeholder={placeholder}
                   value={place}
                   onChangeText={(str) => handlePlace(str)}/>
               <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
                   data={data}
                   keyExtractor={item => item.place_google_id}
                   renderItem={({item}) => (
                       <View style={{backgroundColor: "#000"}}>
                           <Text style={{color: "#FFF"}}>{item.description}</Text>
                       </View>
                   )}
               />
            </View>
            <TextInput style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
};
```

```
flatList: {
    flex: 1,
    left: 10,
    position: "absolute",
    right: 10,
    top: 50,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add zIndex to your flatlist styles :

```
flatList: {
    flex: 1,
    left: 10,
    position: "absolute",
    right: 10,
    top: 50,
zIndex:4 // add this
}
```

Hope it helps . feel free for doubts

Comment: adding zIndex don't work bro.

Comment: share expo snack, please will show there

Comment: [https://snack.expo.dev/@mohamed-nawas/e69da4?platform=android], here is the link, it works in expo snack, but in my emulator, it's showing opposite as red input is above the black flatlist items.

Comment: In the expo snack in android it is working as expected and in ios not, in my both android emulator and ios simulator it is not working. I'm using Pixel_XL emulator, but I don't think it an issue. Also don't know why it behaves differently for ios and android in expo snack